# i'm getting an error the operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int[] int

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

i dont know why i'm getting this error
i changed the "arr+1" in that line to "arr[0]+1" but still it didn't solve it instead i got an error "change method from int[] int to int int"
and ignore that i'm not calling the function.

```
package Ds.Recursion;

public class practice1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    

}
 static boolean sorted(int arr[],int n) {
  if(n==1) {
      return true;
  }
   //getting error in the next line
   boolean restArray = sorted(arr+1,n-1);
   return(arr[0]<arr[1] && restArray) ;
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do `arr+1` in `sorted()`? Java doesn't have array slicing.

Comment: Also, what is this code supposed to do? Remember that there are naming conventions in Java, and you should definitely stick to them: if your method checks whether some array is sorted, call it `isSorted`, not `sorted`. Following the conventions means that when it's time to ask folks for help, the code you show them looks the same as any other Java code. So on that note: classes use CamelCase (capital letters for each distinct word in the class name), and variables are named after the role they play, e.g. `boolean restArray` is a boolean, which can't be an array, so that's a bad name.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
boolean restArray = sorted(arr+1,n-1);
```

Makes me think you are given or have found samples using C or C++. Theses are very different languages.  Doing arithmetic on an array (`arr+1`) makes no sense in Java.

You naming indicates that this is a school assignment of some sort.
I recommend to make sure you are using the language that your classes use to illustrate implementations.

As for the translation to Java, @RaffleBuffle has given you a reasonable idiomatic solution.